# Implementing remember me without a key

Tags: spring, spring-security

i found some samples that implements remember me functionality by just

```
<remember-me/>
```

and other samples implement it as:

```
<remember-me key="_spring_security_remember_me"/>
```

and i want to know what is the difference between the two declarations, and is the **_spring_security_remember_me** is a predefined key?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default key can be found in `AuthenticationConfigBuilder.createRememberMeFilter()`

```
    final String DEF_KEY = "SpringSecured";
```

That is the value that is used if you don't specify one in `<remember-me>`

Comment: is the _spring_security_remember_me is a predefined key

Comment: so what key do you suggest to use ?

Comment: whatever you want to use - the point is to make it something other people could not guess, so you don't want to use the default.

Comment: can you please give me a link to various implementation, or how to define my custom key ?

Comment: `<remember-me key="mycustomkey"/>`

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, you can generate a random key for use using the command `date | md5` in the terminal if you're on a mac or a linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html), the `key` attribute is used in hashing the value stored in the cookie.  It prevents a malicious user from trying to decode the cookie, because they can't do that (well it s a lot harder) without the key.

Comment: is the _spring_security_remember_me is a predefined key ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for the rememberme().key() feature in the future, it seems that as of Spring Boot 2.2.6 there is SecureRandom generator to generate the key if it is not provided. Here is the implementation found in `org.springframework.security.config.http.AuthenticationConfigBuilder.createRememberMeFilter`

```
private String createKey() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    return Long.toString(random.nextLong());
}
```